# passing url matching parameter to reverse() in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

in my urls.py I need to invoke a generic CreateView that requires a success_url parameter. The "success" URL contains an identifier that I need to pass to the reverse() URL search function. I get this parameter from the URL of the CreateView. please see the code below. I need to grab the value of the <pk> parameter in the "create" url, and pass it on to the "success" url. how is this done?

thanks

konstantin

PS: using django trunk

`...
url(r'^path/(?P<pk>\d+)/apply/$',
    generic.CreateView.as_view(form_class=MyForm,
                               success_url=reverse_lazy('success', args=[???<pk>???]),
                               template_name='create.html'), name='create'),
url(r'path/(?P<pk>\d+)/apply/success/$',
    generic.TemplateView.as_view(template_name='success.html'), name='success'),
...`

Comment: The previous answer look like this in the django 1.10 : `success_url="/polls/{id}/"` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin):

> `success_url` may contain dictionary string formatting, which will be interpolated against the object's field attributes. For example, you could use`success_url="/polls/%(slug)s/"` to redirect to a URL composed out of the slug field on a model.